# What colors gets bonus vs other colors?

Tags: doctor-who-legacy

When I am playing I can see that some colors do half damage to some colored enemies and other colors do double damage.

What is a complete list of what bonus/weakness each color has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How damage works:

- If the color is vulnerable to the attack’s color, the damage is
  doubled;
- If the color is resistant to the attack’s color, the damage is
  halved;
- If the color is neutral to the attack’s color, the damage is exactly
  what it said on the tin.

[How](https://drwhopossiblethings.wordpress.com/2013/12/08/doctor-who-legacy-mini-strategy-guide/comment-page-1/) the colors stack up:

1. Red is vulnerable to blue and resistant to green. It is neutral to
   itself, gold, and silver;
2. Blue is vulnerable to green and resistant to red. It is neutral to
   itself, gold, and silver;
3. Green is vulnerable to red and resistant to blue. It is neutral to
   itself, gold and silver;
4. Gold is vulnerable to silver. It is neutral to all other colors;
5. Silver is vulnerable to gold. It is neutral to all other colors.